# Why is this docker image allowed past the firewall?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, ufw

I'm running a docker container that has the port `9000:9000` binding to the host, but I also have *ufw* enabled. The only ports I've allowed are `22, 80, 443`.

So why is it that I'm able to connect to this container using the host's IP address? Shouldn't port `9000` be blocked by `ufw`?

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
14417c4f71fb        dockerui/dockerui   "/dockerui"              2 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp     docker_ui

root@docker:~# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Aren't all ports blocked by default when you enable ufw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker silently modifies iptables. You can start the Docker daemon with the `--iptables=false` option by editing `DOCKER_OPTS` in /etc/default/docker

Comment: Seriously. That's kind of scary because it doesn't show up in the ufw list as open.

Comment: Yeah, I'm surprised that `iptables=false` is not the default option.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @kliew, Docker will add its own iptables chain, granting access to all exposed ports and pre-empting any rules that you define using ufw.

If you're not comfortable completely disabling Docker's control over iptables, though, there is another documented way to have your own rules respected. From the same docs:

> If you need to add rules which load before Docker’s rules, add them to the DOCKER-USER chain. These rules are applied before any rules Docker creates automatically.

Source: https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#add-iptables-policies-before-dockers-rules

This would preclude the use of ufw, though, because ufw only operates within its own iptables chains and doesn't give you control over the DOCKER-USER chain. You'll have to do this using `iptables` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Docker modifies `iptables` and UFW is not aware of this.

This answer describes what is happening and how to fix:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46266757

Please follow it.

Answer (score 1):

adding "--iptables=false" is not a good solution
as I said here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54486957/1712906

a better solution is to add these lines to /etc/ufw/after.rules

```
# BEGIN UFW AND DOCKER
*filter
:ufw-user-forward - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN -s 10.0.0.0/8
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN -s 172.16.0.0/12
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN -s 192.168.0.0/16

-A DOCKER-USER -p udp -m udp --sport 53 --dport 1024:65535 -j RETURN

-A DOCKER-USER -j ufw-user-forward

-A DOCKER-USER -j DROP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -d 192.168.0.0/16
-A DOCKER-USER -j DROP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -d 10.0.0.0/8
-A DOCKER-USER -j DROP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -d 172.16.0.0/12
-A DOCKER-USER -j DROP -p udp -m udp --dport 0:32767 -d 192.168.0.0/16
-A DOCKER-USER -j DROP -p udp -m udp --dport 0:32767 -d 10.0.0.0/8
-A DOCKER-USER -j DROP -p udp -m udp --dport 0:32767 -d 172.16.0.0/12

-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
# END UFW AND DOCKER
```

Answer (score 0):

For me "--iptables=false" did not work and my system doesn't uses ufw, so I created another method.
OS Ubuntu/Debian.

Created directory named iptables in /etc/.

```
mkdir /etc/iptables
cd /etc/iptables
```

Here I saved the rules from the currently working iptables.

```
iptables-save > rules.v4 # IPv4 iptables rules
ip6tables-save > rules.v6 # IPv6 iptables rules
```

Added the following lines in /etc/rc.local

```
#  Flush iptables rules
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
#  Restore iptables rules from files
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4     # Restore ipv4 rules
ip5tables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v6    # Restore ipv6 rules
```

Now at every reboot the iptables rules will be flushed and restored from /etc/iptables/rules.v4 and /etc/iptables/rules.v6.

If you want to modify the ipv4 rules or add more rules you can do it in /etc/iptables/rules.v4 then execute iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4.
If you want to modify the ipv6 rules or add more rules you can do it in /etc/iptables/rules.v6 then execute ip6tables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v6.