# how to connect an application in tomcat container to a postgres container created in the same network?

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking, ubuntu-14.04, firewall

I am running a tomcat based application inside a container, and a Postgres database container on my **ubuntu** host using docker compose. They are in same docker bridge network defined by me. I have my **firewall enabled**. My firewall doesn't have any deny rule for 5432 port. When my firewall is disabled, my tomcat application can connect to a database container by using either its IP or service name. But when the firewall is enabled, it does not connect to the database container. I have set DOCKER_OPTS="--iptables=false" in docker.conf and restarted docker. Why it is not connecting when firewall is enabled?

1)These are my active rules:-

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
2377/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
7946/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
7946/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
4789/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
8443                       ALLOW       10.20.220.185
8443                       ALLOW       10.20.220.78
8081                       ALLOW       10.5.0.7
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere
8081                       ALLOW       10.5.0.5
2377/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
7946/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
7946/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
4789/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5432 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

=========================================================================

2)These is my application configuration to connect to database using service name:-
`driverClass=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://PostgresDatabase:5432/dockerdb
user=dockeruser`

Comment: Have u tried to restart docker? And updating with docker-compose.yml might be helpful.

Comment: yes i tried restarting but same output

Answer (score 0):

Setting `--iptables=false` means that docker daemon could not configure iptables rule(s) on host. However it's kind of essential while you have ufw enabled.
I am sure this issue would disappear after you delete `DOCKER_OPTS="--iptables=false"` in configuration and restart docker daemon.

During start process, Docker daemon would configure some extra iptable rules to make communication going well among containers/between container and outside world, since firewall/ufw would DROP packets by `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY`.

Below, it is a rough process how docker create iptable rules:

1. Enable Enable NAT on docker0 with iptables tool.
   `iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -s 172.17.0.1 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE`
2. Enable communication within containers.
   `iptables -I FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT`
3. Enable communication between container and out world.
   `iptables -I FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT`
4. Accept any packets from outside connections which already established.
   `iptables -I FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack -ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`.

Above all, you have `iptables` set false and firewall enabled without any extra moves. Just like you throw the key away with door locked, but you still want to go outside. So I strongly suggest you not to change any docker network settings before you totally understand the [architecture of docker network](http://success.docker.com/article/networking) and how those components work together.

This is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383845/what-is-the-best-practice-of-docker-ufw-under-ubuntu) asked in a different way. May the answers help you more.