# Ubuntu - firewall rules MySQL on host | Docker containers to host

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, firewall, iptables

Is there any possible way to setup the host firewall to allow connections ***only for the network Docker containers uses?***

### Intro

The only way I was able to connect to a OS hosted MySQL instance from my new Docker containers was by opening to ports:

`sudo ufw allow 3310`

Inside the Docker container I am then able to connect using:

```
 (Docker container): mysql -u testuser -p -h 172.100.0.1 -P 3310
```

However this way the port is open to the internet as well, I would rather use SSH to connect using credentials.

**NOTE: MySQL bind-address=0.0.0.0 is set**

### Information

- On Host:

**NOTE: Showing only applicable Docker network information - my containers use a custom named network (d-custom-network)**

```
  ifconfig

  d-custom-network: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.100.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.100.255.255
    inet6 fe80::42:b8ff:fe7f:c4bf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 02:42:b8:7f:c4:bf  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 473  bytes 34668 (34.6 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 403  bytes 119797 (119.7 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

  docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
    inet6 fe80::42:13ff:fefc:301f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 02:42:13:fc:30:1f  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 28509  bytes 1593290 (1.5 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 33351  bytes 173437123 (173.4 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

- Inside container:

  ```
  ip addr
  1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
  link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  69: eth0@if70: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
      link/ether 02:42:ac:64:00:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
      inet 172.100.0.4/16 brd 172.100.255.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  ```
- Docker network information:

  ```
   docker network ls

   8a35ff6a0a88        bridge                            bridge              local
   572f80997782        magento2-network-frontend         bridge              local
   4590216456c0        host                              host                local
   a79a85d3a426        none                              null                local
  ```
- Docker network inspect:
  *Partial content:*

  ```
   docker network inspect magento2-network-frontend

   [
       {
           "Name": "glo-magento2.3-network-frontend",
           "Id": "572f809977826942d1b582c17f2ac67f25f4221ddfe5a2f504ccb12a3aa6c786",
           "Created": "2020-08-11T12:05:51.988694032Z",
           "Scope": "local",
           "Driver": "bridge",
           "EnableIPv6": false,
           "IPAM": {
               "Driver": "default",
               "Options": null,
               "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.100.0.0/16"
            }
        ]
    },
  ```

Partial iptables listing (Docker destinations) - : *I noticed these connection information when connecting from inside the container when trying to connect in MySQL **testing with a failed login***

```
   FROM Within container:

   ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'testuser'@'cpe-172-100-0-4.twcny.res.rr.com'
   ping cpe-172-100-0-4.twcny.res.rr.com
   PING cpe-172-100-0-4.twcny.res.rr.com (172.100.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from 54195d3486eb (172.100.0.4): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms

   iptables -L 

   Chain DOCKER (2 references)
   target     prot opt source               destination
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             cpe-172-100-0-2.twcny.res.rr.com  tcp dpt:6082
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             cpe-172-100-0-2.twcny.res.rr.com  tcp dpt:6081
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             cpe-172-100-0-3.twcny.res.rr.com  tcp dpt:6379
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             cpe-172-100-0-4.twcny.res.rr.com  tcp dpt:http-alt
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             cpe-172-100-0-5.twcny.res.rr.com  tcp dpt:https
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             cpe-172-100-0-5.twcny.res.rr.com  tcp dpt:http
```

### What I tried

I thought I would be able to use the method mentioned here : *This is also why I investigated how to make sure the docker network name used by host (ie. ifconfig output)*, in my example I created *d-custom-network*

[Direct link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04/#allow-connections-to-a-specific-network-interface)

> To allow access on a specific port let’s say port 3360 only to specific network interface eth2, then
> you need to specify allow in on and the name of the network interface:

```
 $ sudo ufw allow in on eth2 to any port 3306

 $ sudo ufw reload
```

So I tried `sudo ufw allow in on d-custom-network to any port 3310`

That is when I noticed the docker `cpe-172-100-0-2.twcny.res.rr.com` output when trying to force a failed login for testing the location I connect from.

I do not think I understood the usage correctly, and assumed that I could use the internal network `172.100.0.*` where my docker containers connect to/from.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Any assistance please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question, and the following worked for me (all commands run on the host):

1. Identify which network your container is attached to:

   ```
   $ docker inspect mycontainer
   ...
       "Networks": {
           "bridge": {
               "IPAMConfig": null,
               "Links": null,
               "Aliases": null,
               "NetworkID": "b8ecee4683b22db9154f8c3e56b48f371b2bdf663f25d092112fc7eb410a4816",
               "EndpointID": "56cd2b50116f92d49c643457059a0ef0350e14509a16d1b615f806bb62eb4ad5",
               ...
           }
       }
   ...
   ```

   My container `mycontainer` is attached to the network named `bridge`:

   ```
   $ docker network ls
   NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
   b8ecee4683b2   bridge    bridge    local
   f9a4ecf5db2b   host      host      local
   cc168ad8f868   none      null      local
   ```
2. Identify which of the host's network interfaces corresponds to the `bridge` network:

   ```
    $ docker network inspect bridge
    ...
    "Options": {
        ...
        "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
        ...
    },
    ...
   ```

   My network `bridge` corresponds to host network interface `docker0`:

   ```
    $ ip addr
    ...
    3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
        link/ether 02:42:c8:b4:a4:ba brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::42:c8ff:feb4:a4ba/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    ...
   ```
3. Allow traffic from the identified host network interface `docker0`, to port 3310 anywhere:

   ```
   $ sudo ufw allow in on docker0 to any port 3310
   ```

I tested it, and the database port on the host is now:

- accessible when connecting from inside the docker container, and
- filtered by the firewall when trying to connect from the network outside the host.

Also, since we're talking about securing a docker host with UFW, I feel it's important to mention this side note/warning about using UFW with docker, in case you're not already aware: See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383845/what-is-the-best-practice-of-docker-ufw-under-ubuntu/51741599#51741599) for details, in summary, Docker by default may override UFW's firewall rules in ways that a typical user may not be expecting.  In particular, I think that exposing a port on a container via `docker -p` actually punches a hole in your firewall on that port, which UFW does not see or control.

Comment: Thank you, when I get back to this part of Docker I will investigate this further. Can you please clarify `docker0` in your solution, how do I find/get this `docker0` to use as reference?  Regarding Docker/ufw rules, I just seen those entries in `iptables` as shown in my example.  I will investigate the link thanks!

Comment: Good question.  When I first answered, I was not entirely sure myself, but I've now learned a bit more about Docker networking.  Just edited my answer to try to show how I think the interface name should be precisely identified, to the best of my current understanding.

Comment: Thanks David, I needed this information again because I created new custom containers that needed a MYSQL instance hosted on the `host` and connect from within `docker containers`.  I also had a custom network `ip addr showed d-custom-network`.  I wonder why my original attempt (question derived from originally) didn't work, because it seems I tried that last year.  Useful to have references for issues that repeat over time.