# Unable to send Sentry events in Node.js Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, sentry

The Sentry SDK for Node.js is unable to send events to the Sentry server while it's running inside a Docker container. I'm fairly new to running containerized setups on my DigitalOcean Ubuntu 20.04 VPS, so any help is appreciated!

The error:

```
Sentry Logger [Log]: [Tracing] starting gql transaction - GET_REFRESH_TOKEN
Sentry Logger [Log]: [Tracing] Finishing gql transaction: GET_REFRESH_TOKEN.
Sentry Logger [Error]: Error while sending event: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.120.195.249:443
```

The IP is the from Sentry as expected and found here: https://docs.sentry.io/product/security/ip-ranges/#event-ingestion.

Relevant settings:

**Sentry Initialization**

```json
{
  dsn: 'https://<secret>@<secret>.ingest.sentry.io/<secret>',
  environment: 'Testing',
  debug: true,
  integrations: [ Http { name: 'Http', _breadcrumbs: true, _tracing: true } ],
  tracesSampleRate: 1,
  _metadata: {
    sdk: {
      name: 'sentry.javascript.node',
      packages: [Array],
      version: '6.13.3'
    }
  }
}
```

**Docker Compose file**

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    #...

  api:
    container_name: api-${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      API_PORT: 3001
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@db:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}?schema=${DB_SCHEMA}
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - ${API_PORT_INTERNAL}:3001
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
      - /app/node_modules

  db:
    #...
```

**API Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14 AS builder

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY prisma ./prisma/

RUN npm install
RUN npx prisma generate

COPY . .

# Latest LTS version
FROM node:14

# Set default values for environment variables
ENV API_PORT=3001

COPY . .
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package*.json ./

# Bind port
EXPOSE 3001

# Start server
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

If any more details are needed I'll append this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Self-answer after some more investigation:*

It turns out all outside network access from within the containers was blocked. The usage of Sentry was simply the first time this was necessary.

**Problem**

While configuring the VPS firewall (UFW), Docker was bypassing the firewall and exposing unwanted ports. To fix this I disabled `iptables` completely in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```json
{
  "iptables": false
}
```

This does the job but blocks all outside network access from within containers.

**Solution**

All credits for the solution go to @Feng with [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383845/what-is-the-best-practice-of-docker-ufw-under-ubuntu/51741599#51741599) to the following question: [What is the best practice of docker + ufw under Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383845/what-is-the-best-practice-of-docker-ufw-under-ubuntu/51741599).

The solution was to remove the `iptables = false` option and fix it properly in the UFW configuration. You can do this manually as described in his post or do as I did and use his tool: https://github.com/chaifeng/ufw-docker.

**TL;DR**

1. Remove `"iptables": false` from `/etc/docker/daemon.json`
2. Properly set up UFW + Docker using https://github.com/chaifeng/ufw-docker