# Can UFW firewall block ports exposed by Docker containers? (Ubuntu 20.04 server)

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04, ufw

### Summary

As a test I have a Docker a container exposing a port as `0.0.0.0:8101:80`. My UFW is set up for the default to deny. I did not expect to be able to reach it from another device.

As a practice I expose docker ports as `127.0.0.1:port:port` for services behind a proxy, but I would like the firewall to block the port as well.

### System

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- UFW 0.36
- Proxy: Nginx 1.22.1
- Docker 23.0.6
- Docker Compose: 2.17.3

### Test Setup

- UFW Rules:

  ```bash
  $ Status: active
  Logging: on (high)
  Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
  New profiles: skip

  To                         Action      From
  --                         ------      ----
  OpenSSH                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
  Nginx Full                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere
  8103/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
  8104/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
  8107/tcp                   DENY IN     Anywhere
  8108/tcp                   DENY IN     Anywhere
  OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
  Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)         
  8103/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
  8104/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
  8107/tcp (v6)              DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
  8108/tcp (v6)              DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
  ```
- Docker Container listening on 8101:

  - service1: `0.0.0.0:8101->80/tcp` (default using 8101:80 in compose)
- Docker Container listening on 8102 locally:

  - service2: `127.0.0.1:8102->80/tcp`
- Listening on 8103, 8105 & 8107:

  - With `nc -l [port]`

### Client from another computer

| Port | Firewall | Listening | `nc -vz DOMAIN PORT` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8101 | default | docker any | `[domain] [IP] 8101 (ldoms-migr) open` |
| 8102 | default | docker local | `[domain] [IP] 8102 (kz-migr): Connection timed out` |
| 8103 | allow | `nc -l [port]` | `[domain] [IP] 8103 open` |
| 8104 | allow | none | `[domain] [IP] 8104: Connection refused` |
| 8105 | default | `nc -l [port]` | `[domain] [IP] 8105: Connection timed out` |
| 8106 | default | none | `[domain] [IP] 8106: Connection timed out` |
| 8107 | deny | `nc -l [port]` | `[domain] [IP] 8107: Connection timed out` |
| 8108 | deny | none | `[domain] [IP] 8108: Connection timed out` |

### What I think the responses mean

- **Open**: Through firewall and the port is listening from my client (8101, 8103)
- **Connection timed out**: Firewall blocked it (8102, 8105, 8106, 8107, 8108)
- **Connection refused**: Through firewall and the port is NOT listening (8104)

### My Question

Can I make UFW block ports in case someone change a docker compose file and does not add 127.0.0.1?

Comment: There is post that might fix my issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383845/what-is-the-best-practice-of-docker-ufw-under-ubuntu

I haven't read the whole thing yet, but I want to comment before my question might waste anyone's time.

Comment: Here are some posts and articles that will probably fix it.

- A readable article with the fix.
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383845/what-is-the-best-practice-of-docker-ufw-under-ubuntu

- The original post that the article probably used.
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383845/what-is-the-best-practice-of-docker-ufw-under-ubuntu

- A script that both reference as part of the solution
  https://github.com/chaifeng/ufw-docker